# How to create shared language resources with i18next in multi-app node/express & react monorepo?

Tags: shared-libraries, i18next, monorepo, next-i18next, i18next-http-backend

I just started to use i18next in my monorepo (new to it), which has several serverside microservices and a couple of frontends, including several custom library components. Many of the language strings are shared, and some are app specific. I could not decide on a logical way to approach the problem.

Tooling: Typescript - Node/Express - React/Vite - Electron/React (Desktop)

Firstly, questions:

1. Where should I keep the language resources during development? In another library? App in monorepo? Under each library module?
2. From where should I serve them? Something like lang.mydomain.com? Re-dividing them under each app during build (e.g. with Vite)?
3. All examples/tutorials I could reach use a single app and use i18next.js/ts to be included at the app level. I think I need to wrap it into a library module for my purposes. How can I do that, without losing access to its capabilities/types/methods etc? Dynamically creating instances in a higher-order module (the library is extensive, and I'm nearly lost)?

My initial thoughts:

- As many translations will be shared, translating each one will be illogical, they should be shared.
- As there can be many languages, it seems using `i18next-http-backend` is logical for web and embed with `i18next-fs-backend` for desktop app.
- Dividing the resources as common/graphs/tables/ui etc will be logical (these will be divided in a library module hierarchy though).
- A logical way can be to include a module's language resources in the module but that would not help translators, they should be at the same place at the top level in this respect.

PS: I used to use react-intl-universal, it is really easy, but it's release schedule is falling back.

Thank you in advance...